# Как прочесть запись функции с указателем

Tags: c++, c

Изучаю указатели и в одном учебнике нашел вот такое объявление функций:

1. `void (*(*p)(void))(int);`
2. `int (*f(void))();`

Мне не совсем понятно, как эту запись прочесть. Предполагаю, что в первом случае это "указатель на функцию, принимающую void, результат которой - указатель на функцию, принимающую int. Подскажите кто-нибудь, как правильно?

Comment: Изучайте: https://habr.com/ru/post/116255/

Comment: Ну да, вы по сути правильно понимаете. Можно же экспериментально проверить, присвоив значения

Comment: 1) указатель на функцию (void), которая возвращает указатель на функцию (int). 2) функция, возвращающая указатель на фунцию, которая возврвщает int. Это полезно понимать, но редко такая жесть нужна, особенно в Modern C++, где есть `std::function`, `std::bind`, лямбды и т.п.

Comment: такую жесть мне кажется только как головоломки можно использовать :)

Comment: @Ildar Вы правы. Для того и существуют typedef/using, чтоб писать программы понятно :)

Comment: Вот этот сайт - https://cdecl.org/ - помогает в таких разборках сложных выражений. Правда, на английском, но, думаю, это не страшно?

Comment: @Harry английский не проблема, благодарю за полезную ссылку :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Да, (1) расшифровали правильно.

Объявления нужно начинать читать с середины, с имени переменной или функции. (В ситуациях, когда имени нет, например у безымянного параметра функции, то нужно найти то место, где могло бы быть имя. Проще всего найти на глазок.)

Дальше нужно двигаться сначала до упора вправо (до конца или до закрывающей скобки), потом до упора влево (до начала или до парной открывающей скобки). Если мы были внутри скобок, то повторить оба шага снаружи скобок, столько раз сколько нужно.

```
         p               // p - это
                                     // Смотрим вправо - там пусто. Смотрим влево.
        *p               // указатель на
       (*p)                          // Пропускаем скобки. Опять смотрим вправо.
       (*p)(void)        // функцию с параметрами (void), возвращающую
                                     // Теперь влево.
      *(*p)(void)        // указатель на
     (*(*p)(void))                   // Пропускаем скобки. Опять смотрим вправо.
     (*(*p)(void))(int)  // функцию с параметрами (int), возвращающую
                                     // Теперь влево.
void (*(*p)(void))(int)  // void
```

Домашнее задание - повторить то же самое для (2).

Comment: Есть удобное мнемоническое правило..https://habr.com/ru/post/100104/#:~:text=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%C2%AB%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE,%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%B8.

Comment: @Swift Кому как, мне оно наоборот кажется сложнее. Там надо запоминать, с какой стороны начинать спираль, и когда делать "холостые" полоборота.

Comment: Перестает сбивать с толку если определение с квалификаторами... или если не известно, правильное ли выражение или нет (где нибудь в шаблоне). Хотя хочется придушить того кто написал такой ктулху-код

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать сервис https://cdecl.org/.

Тогда:

- `void (*(*p)(void))(int);` <=> `declare p as pointer to function (void) returning pointer to function (int) returning void`.
- `int (*f(void))();` <=> `declare f as function (void) returning pointer to function returning int`.