# Как прочесть запись функции с указателем?

Tags: c++, c, функции, типы-данных

И как прочитать такой код

```
typedef void(*sfc_funcptr_t)();

sfc_funcptr_t* const func_src = (sfc_funcptr_t*)interfaces;
```

Comment: [Как прочесть запись функции с указателем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161743/398802)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прочесть запись функции с указателем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала `sfc_funcptr_t` объявлен как тип (вернее, псевдоним) указателя на фунцию без параметров, ничего не возвращающую:

```
typedef void(*sfc_funcptr_t)();

sfc_funcptr_t* const func_src = (sfc_funcptr_t*)interfaces;
```

А во второй строке объявлен константный указатель на указатель на такую функцию, инициализированный значением `interfaces`.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*