# Для чего писать typedef в объявлении указателя на функцию?

Tags: c++, c

```
typedef int(*Message)(const char* message);
```

Для чего в таких случая писать typedef?Почему нельзя без него,ведь в таком случае мы так же объявим указатель на функцию?Что происходит при данном обьявлении?

Comment: Вы пробовали пользоваться этим "указателем"? Например, присвоить ему значение?

Comment: @dIm0n нет,не пробовал

Comment: Для упрощения кода, декларирующего указатель на функцию. Вообще, typedef делает алиас для типа и обычно имеет вид *`typedef type alias`* (например, **`typedef unsigned int u32`**). Однако, при описании указателя на функцию  `typedef` берет алиас для типа, равным "имени указателя на функцию"  / Далее, в тексте программы вместо описания указателя на функцию в виде `int (*f)(char *, int)` с именем **`f`**, вы можете написать значительно короче -- `foo f;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё как и положено, `typedef` - объявляет тип, а без него будет переменная (указателя на функцию).

```
typedef int(*Message)(const char* message);
// Message - это тип указателя на функцию
int me(const char* message){return 0 ;}
// переменной заданного типа назначаю адрес реальной функции me
Message m = & me ;
Message m2 = me ;
// mep - это указатель на функцию
int (*mep)(const char* message) = & me;
// этому казателю присвоен адрес функции
int rp = (*mep)("");
int rp2 = mep("");
```

Comment: Я просто не понимаю,вот синтаксис typefef:  "typefef (тип) (имя нового типа);" но в данном случае "typedef int(* Message)(const char* message);" получается что int(* Message) объявляется как (const char* message)? Или даже если * Message объявляется как int(const char* message) что более понятно ,то почему в typedef int стоит в части где мы пишем базовый тип?

Comment: Принято так в стандарте с типами функций делать. Имя между входящими типами и исходящим типом.

Comment: @Whitehorse Если у вас С++ - воспользуйтесь using: `using Message = int(*)(const char*);` - так понятнее? Просто слово `typedef` из объявления переменной делает алиас типа...

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, так станет понятно:

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef int(*Message)(const char* message); // алиас для типа
int (*message)(const char* message);        // объявление указателя

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Message, int (*) (const char*)>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(message), int (*) (const char*)>);

Message message_2 = message;

int main() {
    message = message_2;
}
```

Также, возможно, будут полезны ответы на [Как прочесть запись функции с указателем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161743/398802).

Comment: Нет, так не станет понятно для тех, кто только изучает и еще не понимает разницу между типом указателя и указателем