# Как понять какой части относится разыменовывание?

Tags: c++, c

```
((int(*)(int, int))sum)(2,4);
(*(int(*)(int, int))sum)(2,4);
```

Я не понимаю,когда мы добавляем знак указателя,он относится к приведению типа или к разыменовыванию указателя на функцию? Просто я знаю что значок разыменовывания должен стоять вплотную к имени переменной,и тут у меня проблема.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как прочесть запись функции с указателем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1161743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользоваться таблицей [приоритетов и ассоциативности операторов](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Приведения типа в C-стиле `(new_type) expression` имеет такой же приоритет как и оператор разыменовывания `*`. Однако, оба этих оператора имеют ассоциативность **справа-налево**.

Таким образом, выражение

```
(*(int(*)(int, int))sum)(2,4);
```

обрабатывается следующим образом:

1. `sum` явно приводится к типу `int(*)(int, int)`. То есть `sum` явно приводится к указателю на функцию с двумя параметрами типа `int`, возвращающую значение типа `int`.
2. Указатель на функцию разыменовывается. Получаем lvalue, ссылающееся на эту функцию.
3. Используем оператор вызова функции.

> Просто я знаю что значок разыменовывания должен стоять вплотную к имени переменной

Если вы воспользуетесь `reinterpret_cast`, то увидите, что значок разыменовывания совсем не обязан стоять вплотную к имени переменной:

```
( *reinterpret_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(sum) )(2,4);
```