# указатели двухмерные массивы

Tags: c++

Как это можно расшифровать?

```
int (*arr)[2]
```

не понимаю звёздочка это разыменование или это тип указатель на инт?
Если это тип указатель, то почему он внутри скобки?

Comment: Это указатель на массив из 2 int

Comment: Как сказали выше это указатель на пару int-ов. Т.е. `arr++` сдвинет arr на 8  (если sizeof(int) == 4) и т.п.

Comment: См. замечательный [сайт](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*arr%29%5B5%5D) :) Если вынести звездочку, по получим

    `int * arr[2]`

То есть массив из двух указателей на `int`. Скобки нужны для того, чтоб звездочка была применена к `arr`, а не к `int`.

Comment: @Harry не понял. Это разыменование? Раз к arr,

Comment: Это все — объявление переменной. Описание ее типа, так сказать. Когда вы пишете `int*p` — разве здесь есть разыменование?...

Comment: @Harry скобки в которых хранится *arr это всё таки часть синтаксиса ( может приоритеты какие-то соблюдаются)? Я понимаю что без них это массив из указателей на инт

Comment: Да. `int x[2]` — массив из 2 int'ов. Но тут в роли `x` благодаря скобкам выступает `*arr`, т.е. указатель.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1161743/312941